# How to install & Use QtWebEngine Widgets on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, cmake, installation

I am trying to run a Qt project, which is built using cmake. I already have QT and QtCreator installed and it works for other projects. Every time I do `cmake ..`, I get the following error:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5WebEngineWidgets" with any of the following names:

    Qt5WebEngineWidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5webenginewidgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5WebEngineWidgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "Qt5WebEngineWidgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "Qt5WebEngineWidgets" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4. I tried installing it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install bison build-essential gperf flex ruby python libasound2-dev libbz2-dev libcap-dev libcups2-dev libdrm-dev libegl1-mesa-dev libgcrypt11-dev libnss3-dev libpci-dev libpulse-dev libudev-dev libxtst-dev gyp ninja-build
```

as suggested here:
https://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine/How_to_Try

But it doesn't work and gives me :

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libasound2 libasound2-data
2 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 603 kB/2,491 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,527 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libasound2 amd64 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
Ign:2 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libasound2-data all 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4
Err:3 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libasound2-dev amd64 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
Err:4 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpulse-dev amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
Err:2 http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libasound2-data all 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2_1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2-data_1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/alsa-lib/libasound2-dev_1.1.3-5ubuntu0.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ci.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/libpulse-dev_11.1-1ubuntu7.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::24 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The `cmake` is still not successful and gives the same error. How can I install QtWebEngineWidgets? I would prefer to do it via terminal but if there's a way to do it from QT creator, I could do that too.

Note that the project is in C++, not Python. So I don't need QtPy.

Comment: try with: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qtwebengine5-dev`

Comment: I still get some qmail errors during installation but the project works after this so it's good @eyllanesc